# Android : unable to get the ids of the items in listview

Tags: android, json, android-listview, httpclient

i am trying to pass the id of the item clicked in `listview` to the next activity but whenever i click on the item, it always get the id of the last item in the `listview` here is my code

```
String src = a.getText().toString();

            ListView srceve  = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_scr_planner);
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            if(src.length()>0)
            try{

            HttpGet post=new HttpGet("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("eventname", src));
            HttpResponse resp = login.client.execute(post);
            String re = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());

            Log.i("loggg", "error" + re);


            re= "{\"root\": " + re + "}";
            JSONObject root = new JSONObject(re);  
            JSONArray sessions = root.getJSONArray("root");
            Log.i("loggg", "error" + sessions);
            for(int i=0;i<sessions.length();i++){
                HashMap<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                JSONObject e = sessions.getJSONObject(i);
                map2.put("event_name", e.getString("name"));
                map2.put("event_date", e.getString("eventdate"));
                mylist.add(map2);
                id = e.getString("id");

            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SimpleAdapter adapt= new SimpleAdapter(searchevent.this,mylist, R.layout.list_custom ,new String[]{"event_name","event_date"},new int []{R.id.textnam,R.id.textdate});
        srceve.setAdapter(adapt);

        srceve.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
                    int pos, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+ id + evename, 0).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(searchevent.this, eventDetails.class);
                i.putExtra("ar", id);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

please tell me where i am wrong and i am retrieving the id of the items which are coming from the server. thanks

Comment: try with this, i.putExtra("ar", pos);

Comment: where your are setting the value for `id` ?

Comment: Provide us the code of your adapter please.

Comment: with `i.putExtra("ar", pos);` i will get the position of the item but i am passing `id` which is the id of that particular item. i am retrieving `id` using json...

Comment: Then you should get the `id`, based on the selected item..i.e.inside `onItemClick`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<sessions.length();i++){
            HashMap<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
            JSONObject e = sessions.getJSONObject(i);
            map2.put("event_name", e.getString("name"));
            map2.put("event_date", e.getString("eventdate"));
            mylist.add(map2);
            id = e.getString("id");

        }
```

every time you are overriding the value of `id`, that's why it's always the last..you should save it in an array like..

```
String[] ids = new String[sessions.length()];
for(int i=0;i<sessions.length();i++){
            HashMap<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
            JSONObject e = sessions.getJSONObject(i);
            map2.put("event_name", e.getString("name"));
            map2.put("event_date", e.getString("eventdate"));
            mylist.add(map2);
            ids[i] = e.getString("id");

        }
```

then in the `onItemClick`, get it based on the position of the selected item:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
                int pos, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);

            String id = ids[pos];

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+ id + evename, 0).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(searchevent.this, eventDetails.class);
            i.putExtra("ar", id);
            startActivity(i);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   srceve.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
                int pos, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String id=parent.getId();//this will give you the id of the selected item View
        parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+ id + evename, 0).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(searchevent.this, eventDetails.class);
        i.putExtra("ar", id);
        startActivity(i);
      }
    });
```